# count the number of row line in a tabular image using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing

how can i count the number of row line in the image. I try some method but i can't find out the real number of the line

[image]

Comment: Have you made an attempt?

Comment: img = np.array(image)
 threshold = np.histogram(img, 3)[1][1]
 img1 = img < threshold
vert_lines = sum(np.mean(img1, axis=0) > 0.5)